# how can I insert a foreign key into a table using JPA?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have two entities which have OneToMany relation when I try to insert some data using em.persist I have Null as value in the foreing key(because I don't insert the primary key in the first table because it was autoincrement)Some one can help me..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you'd like to persist the child object with the father you need to extend your `@OneToMany` annotation with the `cascade`-attribute. You need `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` or `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much I have done this but only in @ManyToOne relation

Answer (score 0):

Just persist the father-object. The primary key shold be filled then.
After that, persist the child.

Comment: thank you for your response..In fact in the father-object I have a list which represent the child so I don't êrsist the child I only insert the value of the list and then I add this set the list into to father and after that I persist the father (I don't persist the child )

Comment: I tryed to do as you have said but I have this error `WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST:` it's verry stronge..How can I do that?

Comment: Can some one help me please ??because I can't do as it said in the unswer belove